# Beamer fancy boxes

Tags: beamer, boxes, fancybox

[[image: 1]I am trying to add ovalbox to my text but not getting it properly. The remaining text that should be in the oval box but it is not seen on the screen. Please help.

[image].com/WgMw6.png

Comment: I am sorry if i asked the question wrongly as it is my first time here. And also my first question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you used  the `fancybox` package to generate the ovalbox, the easiest way to keep the content within the bounds of the frame is to insert it into a parbox of that width.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer} 

\usepackage{fancybox} % added for ovalbox

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Ovalbox}
    \ovalbox{\parbox{\framewidth}{The BEAMER package, wich defines the beamer document class, is generally included in most of standart LaTex distributions.}}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `fancybox` you can use a `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer} 

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} % added for ovalbox

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Ovalbox}
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white]
    The BEAMER package, wich defines the beamer document class, is generally included in most of standart LaTex distributions.
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also nice examples taken from https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook

[image]

[image]

[image]